# How to see the encryption algorithm in firefox

Tags: firefox, encryption, plugins

Is there any tool through which I can check the encryption algorithm being used when I am accessing a website in firefox? The plug in should be able to show me security related information, like exchange of certificates with time stamps etc at the beginning of the TCP communication; used encryption algorithm if AES 128, 256 etc. 
Basically, was looking for anything close to Wireshark but as a plugin in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I see the encryption algorithm in firefox?

You can get some of the information you are looking for by clicking on the [Site Identity Button](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure) (a globe, triangle or padlock icon on the left end of the address bar) and then "More information".

> The Technical Details section displays whether the connection is encrypted for privacy reasons, and if so, what type or strength of encryption was used.

[image]

[image]

---

#### Further reading

- [Page Info window - View technical details about the page you are on](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/page-info-window-view-technical-details-about-page)